# using 'or' condition in re.split

Tags: python, split

I have a list of strings each one of those needs to be split when an 'y' or 'm' is found:

```
mylist = ['3m10y','10y20y','18m2y']
```

in the following items:

```
splitlist = [['3m','10y'],['10y','20y'],['18m','2y']]
```

i was thinking of using re.split() but I cannot use the 'or' condition in order to tell the function to split either when it finds an 'm' or an 'y'.

any help appreciated!
thanks

Comment: Show us the code you have tried.

Comment: Why can't you use or? The split method takes a regex pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `findall` instead of `split`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d+[ym]', '3m10y')
['3m', '10y']
```

`[my]` is `m` or `y`.

Comment: `splitlist = map(lambda l: re.findall(r'\d+[ym]', l), mylist)`

Comment: @Anentropic You mean `[re.findall(r'\d+[ym]', s) for s in mylist]`?

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> items = re.split(r'(m|y)', '10m2y4m55y55y53m')
>>> items
['10', 'm', '2', 'y', '4', 'm', '55', 'y', '55', 'y', '53', 'm', '']
>>> [''.join(p) for p in zip(items[::2], items[1::2])]
['10m', '2y', '4m', '55y', '55y', '53m']
```